# Can I split one Ethernet line coming out of my wall into multiple separate lines?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, switch

I live in an apartment which provides Internet service included in the rent.
They use a company called Pavlov for the Internet http://pavlovmedia.net/

wireless seems to be working fine but wired connection is at least %30 faster.

Ethernet, Cat5 outlet is built in the wall, and there is only 1 outlet in each room.

**I would like to take this 1 outlet coming out the wall and multiply it into 4 wires, for desktop, Playstation, TV and laptop, without losing any Internet bandwidth.**

I have absolutely no idea whether this line is coming from a switch or a router but I have been researching Ethernet splitter, routers, switches, hubs and haven't found a solid answer.

Is there a way I can do this?

This picture cleared up few things:

[image]

It seems that an Ethernet switch is to Ethernet as a USB hub is to USB, but with packet inspection.  What is a 10/100Mbps Network Switch, actually, and what is the cap?

Comment: You just need to plug a switch into the wall socket, and plug everything else into the switch (netgear do a 5 port switch).  Assuming they haven't locked it down to an IP per outlet somehow, this is normal practice.

Comment: thank you Paul. i believe you are talking about http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=383560&csid=_61

Comment: @Gee - no, Gigabit Ethernet requires 4 pairs and has done so for 20 years. So using a splitter will always downgrade both lines to 100 Mbps.

Answer (score 10):

You need something like this, it's an Ethernet switch, it's basically a more sophisticated hub. 10/100Mbit if you don't have faster Internet. No need for setting up, just plug and play. [http://amzn.com/B00002EQCW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00002EQCW)[image]

But talk to your provider first and as for possibility of using this one, they maybe blocking access only for one computer at a time.

Comment: If your provider allows multiple IP address, get a Switch as above. Otherwise, you need a router (more complex setup)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you purchase a router and plug it to the port. A router has an advantage over a switch in this situation, if your ISP is blocking access to one computer at a time.

A router is probably almost as cheap as a switch these days and far more prevalent among consumer setups. A typical consumer router is actually a router + network switch + wireless access point. So if you already have a wifi router, you would likely be able to use it directly, since most routers should come with 4 ethernet slots as well.

Answer (score 0):

Been looking into the same thing but different reasons. Your options are a switch box (ISP as stated previously needs to be checked. TWC limits to one modem access).

A splitter, though you must remember you half the bandwidth with each splitter if both devices are running it and in your case Quarter it if you had all 4 pulling on the bandwidth at the same time though in your and my situation improbable.

A router. Great option for you as your going directly off the connection line and the router will provide as a splitter under a single IP.

And a Access point which sadly I'm fearing more and more is my only option. If you go with this option get a Duel band router and access point. The router and access point need to have signal strength of 300mbs each as the access point will use the 5GHz channel to receive from the router and output through the 2.4GHz channel as well as the ethernet ports on the back or front depending on model. Drawback to this is you will limit your future proofness of your home if the ISP's ever give true fiberwire bandwidth of 1Gbs. If your on the Google fiberwire city list go the rout of the router as all other ISPs in the area will raise their bandwidth to stay a competitor. If your not and you don't plan to live their longer than 4 years and already have a duel band router go for the access point.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above. You said they’re already hardwires going to each room, so in any case you be splitting up already split lines. Find the source and upgrade/replace if at all possible to a higher multi port switch, router, hub, or whatever is being provided by you apartment.