# Is there a simple way to split internet on one line so that it can be accessible in two places?

Tags: networking, modem, cable, splitter

Before I add more detail, I would like to stress that I am not a computer person so please be patient with me!

So - I live in the remote Scottish Highlands, have satellite broadband, and have a modem with only one port for the cable to go to computer (no wireless option).

I would like to have access to the internet in two separate locations (one in the same room as the modem, the other in another room).

I was hoping to put in one long cable from the modem, then attach a splitter cable, and have two separate wires coming out from that to reach the two different locations, so that everything can remain connected up (accepting the internet can only be used on one connection at a time).

I have since realised this doesn't seem to be possible. I've tried to understand the reasons for this but my brain can't make sense of the way it is explained.

My questions as follows:
1 - is there ANY simple way to achieve what I am trying to do or is it a total lost cause and better to look into getting a new modem with multiple ports? 
2 - what is the point of splitter cables existing if they can't be used in the way that seems logical? Am I missing something?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: This has been asked before. Let me look up the question. (short answer is 'No: just spliiting the cable will not work'.

Comment: All you need is an Ethernet switch, which allows you to connect multiple cables together on the same network. But you may want to consider a wireless router or access point, which will give you multiple Ethernet ports and a wireless networks for mobile 'phones and tablets. Which you need will depend on whether there is routing firmware in the satellite modem.

Comment: Please read these links:

1) http://superuser.com/questions/764576/why-does-just-splitting-an-ethernet-cable-not-work

2) http://superuser.com/questions/814364/can-i-use-a-ethernet-splitter-to-connect-a-router-to-two-devices (already a duplicate, but with nice pictures)

3) http://superuser.com/questions/514938/can-i-split-one-ethernet-line-coming-out-of-my-wall-into-multiple-separate-lines

Comment: Could you give us more information on the modem?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a switch. Basically, it's a box that allows connected computers talk to each other (this includes your router).

They can go for fairly cheap. I recommend a 5-port gigabit switch, and they can be found for ~$20 USD.

Comment: not to confuse things but if its a 'simple' one line modem, wouldn't a consumer router be more appropriate?

Comment: Based on the question, it sounds like it's a combo modem/router with only one rj45 port and no wireless. If OP wanted wireless with the least amount of hassle, then a general purpose router with a built-in WAP would be great, but if all they want is another ethernet connection, then a switch is perfect.

Comment: More info on the hardware really would be nice. For all we know, its USB and we're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, modern, base T ethernet isn't like power or a phoneline with a simple splitter. You can't simply inject a signal into an existing cable with modern flavours of ethernet

A quick look at a few scottish satillite ISPs suggests what you need is a simple, basic consumer router - plug in the ethernet cable from the modem to the wan socket, and whatever else to the other sockets and you should be good. Some of them even sell them. You shouldn't have very much trouble getting suitable at any computer or electronics store.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what OS you had. I remember in 2002, the first year that Windows XP came out I was ablt to simply share an internet connection with my brothers laptop until a WinXP update disabled that networking possibility and made it only possible on Windows XP Pro versions. This internet sharing is still included on Windows 7 Pro and Ultimate and 10 Pro. This would of course require a 2nd Ethernet nic card which are cheaper than routers and switches.

But to your original question, NO, it is not possible to simply split an Ethernet wire. There has to be some kind of hub to route traffic to the desired device or machine as in a router or switch. Routing capability at the client in terms of sharing the connection

Comment: arguably. A basic, low end switch is *really* cheap, especially per port. And you'd need to have a desktop for PCI(e) ethernet cards, or use USB-ethernet adaptors